# org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: jboss, zk

I followed the [this tutorial](http://%20https://forum.zkoss.org/question/77042/how-to-deploy-zk-to-jboss-701/) to deploy Zk on Jboss 6 but on server start up I am getting the error below:

> ERROR
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/stream-zk]]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) JBWEB000289: Servlet zkLoader threw
> load() exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet cannot be cast to
> javax.servlet.Servlet
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
> [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100)
> [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593)
> [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802)
> [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
> at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
> [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_261]
> at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Such error "...cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet..." is mostly caused by a class that doesn't extend `HttpServlet`, but ZK really extends `HttpServlet`.

So the root cause is probably from Jboss.
According to this [thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/220751) you might load 2 different versions of the servlet API jar.

According to [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/class_loading_and_modules):

> *This is a flat namespace and there should not be multiple instances of a class in different deployment JARs. If there are, only the first
> loaded will be used and the results may not be as expected*

Please check this first.